# Where "Color" (Material, Object, Vertex, Single, Random & Texture) from "Viewport Shading"?

Tags: blender, 3d-modelling

I have Blender 2.92. I looked at the documentation, there is no mention at all.
Screenshots:
[2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QFzq.png)
[2.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVZSY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change Viewport Shading to solid

[image: Screenshot]